# How to update CPAN perl module

Tags: linux, perl, cpan

I'm trying to install some perl module but everytime this message is shown

```
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.00) available.
  [Currently running version is v1.960001]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.
```

I've tried to do

```
install CPAN
reload cpan
```

With

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.960001)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install CPAN
```

But the result is

```
Going to read '/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Going to read '/root/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Mon, 28 Oct 2013 23:41:06 GMT
  HTTP::Date not available
  ..............
  New CPAN.pm version (v2.00) available.
  [Currently running version is v1.960001]
  You might want to try
    install CPAN
    reload cpan
  to both upgrade CPAN.pm and run the new version without leaving
  the current session.


...............pi@raspbmc:~$
```

The version is still 1.960001.

Comment: This looks like a crash. Is this a raspberry pi? Do you have enough memory to run CPAN.pm?

Comment: Hi, it's a raspberry pi !
Should I use cpanm ?

Comment: After loading all indexes, the CPAN shell takes some 300MB on my amd64 system. This may be too much for your system. cpanm is probably better, as it does not load the indexes into memory.

Comment: Can I create a swap on my 16gb sd card ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. And it's just a guess that you're running out of memory. Do you see something in the log files in /var/log?

Comment: Look at the latest ones.

Comment: Oct 30 09:55:49 raspbmc kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 16133 (cpan) score 433 or sacrifice child

Comment: OK. So probably try cpanm or more memory (swap?). Theoretically you can use `SQLite` with `CPAN.pm` (using the module `CPAN::SQLite`), but only theoretically, as initially building the `SQLite` database will probably need the same amount of memory as now.

Comment: I solved the memory problem by making a swap & turn off Xbmc during the installation

"sudo initctl stop xbmc"

Comment: OK, so it's probably best if you write an answer to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. download CPAN module from this page http://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN
2. untar it (`tar zxf CPAN-2.00.tar.gz`), cd into the directory and run

   ```
   perl Makefile.PL
   make test
   sudo make install
   ```

edit: if it breaks making a path with :: in it then perhaps your filesystem type does not support these characters in a filename

To see the filesystem type, run `mount` without any parameters and all the mounted filesystems with their types will be shown

The error `Can't write-open blib/man3/CPAN::Admin.3pm` seems to suggest a filesystem problem, but ext4 in rw mode sounds alright.  Try this from the `CPAN-2.00` directory

```
perl -e 'open($f,">blib/man3/CPAN::thisisatest") || die $!;'
```

Comment: Step 1) : OK
Step 2) 
perl Makefile.PL  OK
make test OK (PASSED)
sudo make install (ERROR)

Manifying blib/man3/CPAN::Admin.3pm
Can't write-open blib/man3/CPAN::Admin.3pm: Invalid argument at /usr/share/perl/5.14/ExtUtils/Command/MM.pm line 141
make: *** [manifypods] Error 22

Comment: Are you running a filesystem that doesn't allow :: in filenames?  msdos filesystems do not, for example

Comment: It's a debian based system (raspbmc)

Comment: Even a debian based system may mount dos filesystems. So better check using `df -T` or `mount`.

Comment: I was do this on my usb disk. After CP on root partition Ext4, It's work fine !

Comment: @AlxAlx: Can you tell us what file system the USB disk has? I typically get ones that are FAT. I have to reformat them myself. Knowing your answer will help us nail down your issue for the next guy. :)

Answer (score 28):

The following procedure

1. `kuz1@banana:~$ sudo perl -MCPAN -e shell`
2. `cpan[1]> install CPAN`
3. `cpan[2]> reload cpan`

works for me on the BANANA Pi Single-Board Computer with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I can confirm this also for Raspbian Wheezy on Raspberry Pi 2

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 14

Comment: This process should work and it's mentioned in the original question as *not working* I don't see what question it answers!

Comment: Why does someone downvoting it?